# Converting Serverless framework to Typescript CDK - API Gateway authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have a `GatewayConstruct` where I want to grant access to users. Looking at the docs I can do something like:

```js
const methodResult = resource.addMethod(method, lambdaIntegration, {
  authorizationType: AuthorizationType.IAM,
});

iamUser.attachInlinePolicy(new Policy(this, 'AllowBooks', {
  statements: [
    new PolicyStatement({
      actions: [ 'execute-api:Invoke' ],
      effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      resources: [ methodResult.methodArn ]
    })
  ]
}))
```

This is all fine, but where/how do I get the current user `iamUser` in order to attach the inline policy?

I'm coming from a Serverless Framework stack and trying to migrate it to CDK. Previously I was just loading a resource such as

```yaml
Resources:
  CognitoAuthorizedApiPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: ${self:custom.stage}-CognitoNotesAuthorizedApiPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              - "execute-api:Invoke"
            Resource:
              !Sub 'arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${ApiGatewayRestApi}/*'
      Roles:
        - !ImportValue '${self:custom.sstApp}-CognitoAuthRole'
```

And calling it in the serverless.yaml file where I didn't need to attach it specifically.

```
resources:
  - ${file(../../resources/cognito-policy.yml)}
```

Would love some direction here, I can't find much in the docs of a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new user via https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.User.html#construct-props

If the user already exists, you can look him up e.g. by ARN via https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.User.html#static-fromwbruserwbrarnscope-id-userarn

Once you have IUser object available, you can attach your desired inline policy to him.